# safari ios div position fixed vanished

Tags: javascript, html, css

i have a modal(position fixed ...) with one input inside it.
every time i start typing something, all of the content just go overlap, like z-index -99999, something like that.

this problem is on safari ios, only.
i tried to force in the main div zindex 9999..., also on the input, but the problem continues.

http://www.e-konomista.pt/artigo/isencao-imi-para-idosos/
the modal is position fixed bottom, if doesnt appear, just refresh.

udealsonline.s3.amazonaws.com/ekonomista/1.png
udealsonline.s3.amazonaws.com/ekonomista/2.png

help guys, and sorry for my english

Comment: In your code, why do you have a `<div class='col-md-4'>` and `<div class='col-md-8'>` nested under your `<div class='col-md-12'>`?

Comment: good point, but forget that look at this pictures
http://udealsonline.s3.amazonaws.com/ekonomista/1.png
http://udealsonline.s3.amazonaws.com/ekonomista/2.png